Visual Studio Code Causes Chrome to Freeze
When I switch to Chrome while using Visual Studio Code, Chrome freezes for a short time, but my computer does not freeze. I uploaded a sample video for you Watch this
I don't fully understand what is causing this issue. I hope you can help me
